# Suppress Duplicate Rows only in the Same Page

Tags: birt

I am using Suppress Duplicate function to prevent the same item code to be displayed more than once. 
I have just one question:
Is it possible to hide the duplicates only in the same page? 
For example, Item Code "1111" is displayed in Page-1, no duplication is shown under it. But in case "1111" has a long list in other columns and continues to Page-2, is it possible to display the item code in the first row of Page-2 and then suppressed again? So if it has an even longer list and extends to Page-3, the item code can be displayed again in the top row?

Comment: you can use group on Item Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a group by on the item code and place the information about in the group header. That way there are no duplicates, but you have the option to repeat the header with information on each new page.

Comment: The important part is to go to the header cell and choose "Drop: Detail" to prevent the extra header row. That way the item code "drops" to the first detail row of the page and the header row collapses to zero height (more or less, there are some caveats)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comment. 
It is already grouped by the item code. But I cannot use the table header to display the code because one item code is not always repeated. So one page might have 2 item codes only, but the next page might have 50 different codes. In the latter case, using the table header can be tricky(probably need to iterate the table for 50 times?). Also it is tricky because my report layout has to be consistent with the excel layout sample prepared by my client.
Thank you for your input anyway.